# Laravel - specify fields returned for collection resource

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection resource like this:

```
class VehicleCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
        ];
    }
}
```

And I call this, for example:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::where('id', '>', 0);

        $collection = new VehicleCollection($vehicles->paginate(10));

        return $collection->preserveQuery();
    }
```

It's important I preserve the pagination query, which is why I didn't use `VechicleResource` - it doesn't have the option to `preserveQuery()`.

The above works fine but it returns too many fields. For example my `Vehicle` table has a `model_name` and a `rating` column. How can I only return the `model_name` (or specify which fields I do return) for each model in the response here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `VechicleResource::collection()` which return `AnonymousResourceCollection` and `AnonymousResourceCollection` extends `ResourceCollection`, so you can call `preserveQuery()`. Then you can pick/specify which field you want to send in `VechicleResource`.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => VechicleResource::collection($this->collection),
    ];
}
```